# Why is composer using the unpatched version of a file?

Tags: php, github, composer-php

I forked a repository and patched a yml file in my forked repository in order to give it valid yml formatting.

https://github.com/patrickmaynard/SonataMediaTwigExtensionBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/services.yml

... but I now find that when I run `composer install` the old, unpatched version of the file is being pulled in.

The relevant parts of my `composer.yml` file look like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@github.com:patrickmaynard/SonataMediaTwigExtensionBundle.git"
    }
],
```

... and this:

```
    "socialbit/sonatamediatwigextension-bundle": "master@dev"
```

**What can I do to force composer to use my patched version of the file?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `composer install`uses the composer.lock file and therefore installs a predefined set of packages. What you instead want is to `composer update` so it checks your packages new version.

Comment: Thanks! I used `composer update socialbit/sonatamediatwigextension-bundle` to update just that package, and it looks like everything worked.